# HQL Hibernate select new Entity() when Entity is null

Tags: hibernate, hql

Ok, so let me elaborate on the title a bit. Say i have an Entity that has a ChildEntity with a bidirectional mapping between the two:

```
+--------+            +-------------+
| Entity | <--1.1---> | ChildEntity | 
+--------+            +-------------+
    |
    |            +-----------------+
    +---1..n---> | SomeOtherEntity |
                 +-----------------+
```

Now lets say i have the HQL that does something like this:

```
FROM ChildEntity as ce 
LEFT JOIN ce.entity as e
LEFT JOIN e.someOtherEntities as soe
WHERE e.user = :user 
 ... (and a bunch of other conditions ) ...
```

So, to the essence of my problem:
There may be cases where a user doesn't have an association with the Entity object, **in those cases i want to be able to create it for him.**

I know it is possible to do something like this:

```
SELECT new Entity(....) FROM .....
```

But is there any way i can do this as a if condition? Like, `if ce.entity == null then new Entity(ce), else e`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this should be handled in code not a query (don't even know a way to do it). the `SELECT new Entity(....) FROM` form is there to create DTOs or ViewModels from parts of the entity, no data manipulation.

```
results = "FROM ChildEntity as ce WHERE ce.entity = null" // get all without entity

for(childentity child : results)
{
    child.setEntity(new Entity());
}
session.Flush();
// query again with what you have
```